# Return confirm cancel button not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony, twig

I have this link in twig  :

```
<a href="{{ path('relation-delete', {'id': c.getCustomerId}) }}" 
   onclick="return confirm('{% trans %}relation.delete{% endtrans %}');"
   class="tip" data-original-title="Verwijder klant {{ c.getCustomerName }}">
```

The HTML in the source :

```
<a href="/app_dev.php/projects/delete/1" class="tip" 
  data-original-title="Verwijder project Lantaarn plaatsen" 
  onclick="return confirm('Verwijderen');">

<button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></button></a>`
```

the onlick confirm cancel button doesn't cancel the action but just keeps going. 
Somebody knows what's wrong with this return confirm ?

Comment: You have to show the result html, not template

Comment: Add this into the question

Comment: Done, any ideas on this ?

Comment: any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: Why you place `button` inside `a` element?

Comment: No errors in the console..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can validade the confirm box outside of html element, in a function and, call this function on 'onclick' event. Like this:

```
<a href="somePage" onclick="return myFunction()">My link</a>

function myFunction() {
    if (confirm("Confirm message")) {
       // do stuff
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out this was causing the problem in a other javascript file: 


`$("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });`

Answer (score 6):

Adding `event.preventDefault();` fixed it.

Here is an example:

```
console.log('Validating...');

function confirm_delete(){
var txt;
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
if (r == true) {
    txt = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    event.preventDefault();
}
console.log(txt);
}
```

Comment: or that "return false;" statement would do the trick to I suppose, I missed it when I was reading it first...